# Custom file import: 'No module named 'filemgr''

Tags: python, import, module, path, package

In my python project I have a file name 'base_file().py'
Into that file I'm attempting to import a file named 'filemgr.py'

My import statement is:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Google Drive\\Stratham Green\\Electric\\Python Projects\\uiProject\\fileManager')
import filemgr
```

Running this code results in

> No module named 'filemgr'

sys.path() results in the following paths:

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\Google Drive\Stratham Green\Electric\Python Projects\uiProject (THIS FOLDER CONTAINS 'base_file().py')
    [separated for readability]
C:\Users\XXXXX\Google Drive\Stratham Green\Electric\Python Projects\uiProject\fileManager  (THIS FOLDER CONTAINS 'filemgr.py')
```

I've tried moving the filemgr.py outside the path of the base_file().py path.
Rather than the explicit path, I've tried the relative path.
I've tried    'import filemgr', 'from filemgr import [function name]', 'from filemgr import *'
I tried to add this as a package but I think that is beyond me at this time

UPDATE: I copied the filemgr.py file and renamed it deleteme.py. I pasted this file in the various sys.path folder and it still was not recognized.

Comment: I edited your post to clean up the formatting mess you made. Please do not undo it again.

Comment: Did I undo your edits? It was not obvious that you did edits. I'm resisting being equally as snarky so instead I will say 'thank you'.

Comment: It appears you and I edited at almost the same time, which appeared like you reverted my edit. I intended no *snark*, and I'm not sure what part of my comment you interpreted that way, but I apologize. I thought I was pretty polite - I even said please. :-)

Comment: That should be my biggest problem in life...

Being new to Python and the Pycharm IDE I was struggling with the import function but have decided to simplify by putting all functions in one file. That's not the solution that I'd like to update this problem with but it is an acceptable workaround.

I wasn't aware that you were cleaning up my post at the same time I was trying to make it more readable. I greatly appreciate your expertise and the expertise of others who give your time and serve as a safety net for folks. Again thank you.